# DVConstraint.createNumericConstraint not working

Tags: apache-poi

Hi I wanted to make a column in my apache poi created excel as number only and I wrote the code by the book. But when the excel is generated it still accepts string values.

```
private void setTemplateDatavalidationNumeric(Sheet sheet,int columnNo){
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 20000, columnNo, columnNo);
    DVConstraint constraint = DVConstraint.createNumericConstraint(DVConstraint.ValidationType.INTEGER,
            DVConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN, "1", String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, constraint);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

}
```

please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code works for me as expected using `apache poi 4.0.1`. Are you sure, you are testing in the correct column? In `apache poi` column numbers are 0 based. Column number 0 is `A`, 1 is `B`, 2 is `C` and so on.

Comment: yeah i checked the cell number based zero error first. the code is right and is working in other systems. but not in mine. may be because i am also using date type validation and list type validation in othen columns. and the validations are overlapping or too much to process with.

Comment: "may be because i am also using ... and ... and ...": And how shall we know this all from your small code snippet you are providing in your question? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the problem. Else no help possible.